# Azure Media Player - display encoding progress or some sort message while encoding is in progress

Tags: rest, azure, azure-media-services

As you know in Azure Media Services encoding is little long running task/job. I would like to enable a feature on Azure Media Player which displays some sort of message on Azure Media Player. Message maybe anything like "This video is being encoded" or "Encoding in progress - 57%" etc.

Just wanted to know if any plugin or something already available for this requirement.

**I think this will work:**
If there is no any plugin or something already available, we can get this status by service calls origin from Azure Media Player js files. Do you think this will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Media Service Encoding` is a `Job`, what you have to do is check the status of job. You may find this link helpful for checking the status of a job - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-rest-check-job-progress/.